# grep: how to get number between two pieces of text

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I want to grep my cpu temp.

When i type in: 
`ipmi-sensors -s 2352` 
I get: 
`2352: CPU Temp (Temperature): 30.00 C (NA/81): [OK]`

I would like to grep the number between "(Temperature):" and "C"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep -oP`:

```
ipmi-sensors -s 2352 | grep -oP '\(Temperature\):\s*\K[\d.]+'
30.00
```

If your `grep` doesn't support `-P` option then use this awk:

```
ipmi-sensors -s 2352 | awk -F '.*\\(Temperature\\): *| C .*' '{print $2}'
30.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way also

```
ipmi-sensors -s 2352 | awk -F'[: ]' '{print $7}'
```

`sed` version

```
ipmi-sensors -s 2352 | sed 's/[^)]\+): \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/'
```

**Output:**

```
30.00
```